# Show Python doc strings for the current function in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: python, sublimetext, sublimetext2

I just found Sublime Text 2 and it's awesome. The only thing I really miss is the ability to view the doc string of the function I'm dealing with. Are there any plugins that can do this?

for example:

```
def f(x):
    '''a doc string for f'''
    print x

f # << at this point, either automatically or with a keystroke,
  # I would like to be able to somehow view "a doc string for f"
```

**Edit:** I've already attempted to using SublimeCodeIntel and SublimeRope, neither have such support.

**Edit2:** It should also work for other modules in the open project.

Comment: SublimeCodeIntel does this fairly reliably for me, by taking me to the function definition. In what way does it not work for you?

Comment: I would like a way to view the doc of the function without having to "go into" a function. A quick glance of the doc rather than a complete shift of scope is what I'm hoping for.

Comment: So SublimeCodeIntel works for you, but if it produced the doc in a pop up display or something,and left your cursor where it was - it would solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By tweaking SublimeCodeIntel, you can disable the "jump" to the file where the function is defined -- this will allow you to see the function definition in the status bar upon alt-clicking.

To do this, select *Preferences > Browse Packages* and then open  *SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel.py*.

Go to `class GotoPythonDefinition(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):` and add a `return` at line 890 so that the first lines of `_trigger` read:

```
        def _trigger(defns):
            if defns is not None:
                defn = defns[0]
                if defn.name and defn.doc:
                    msg = "%s: %s" % (defn.name, defn.doc)
                    logger(view, 'info', msg, timeout=3000)
                    return
```

(you can also tweak the `msg` string formatting and remove the `defn.name` to save a bit of status bar space).

It's a bit disorienting to have to look down at the status bar to see the definition... also, the status bar won't be able to display long definitions. However, it's a start. Hopefully, tooltip/popup control will be made available through the API so that definitions can appear in the view next to alt-clicked functions.

Comment: I didn't mention [SublimePeek](https://github.com/jlegewie/SublimePeek) in my answer, as its "Quick Look" popup seemed relatively annoying to me (much more than a glance at the status bar)... Just throwing it out there in case it could interest you.

Answer (score 4):

Something like [this](https://github.com/kemayo/sublime-text-2-goto-documentation) will point to the correct place in the documentation, but if you really need documentation integrated into your environment, I would consider using an IDE. However, I too am a fan of Sublime and just pop open a browser when needed.

Comment: Looking at the code to the package (and trying it a bit) it appears to not be very "smart" in that it only works for builtin functions and root level modules. For example, it will only search for `f` if I search at the end of `my_module.f`, resulting in no documentation found. The same is true for class instances with `self.f`.

Answer (score 4):

[Install anaconda for sublime](http://damnwidget.github.io/anaconda/).

Then on Sublime3, navigate to `Preferences > Package Settings > Anaconda > Settings-User` and add the following lines to the text file just opened.

```
{
    "anaconda_linting" : false,
    "enable_signatures_tooltip" : true,
    "merge_signatures_and_doc" : true,
    "python_interpreter":"/home/miladiouss/anaconda3/bin/python"
}
```

Save, restart Sublime, and enjoy the best IDE for Python!

Comment: This worked for me! Creates a nice tooltip.
@Miladiouss change the path of python_interpreter to something all users would have, not your specific home dir. I used "python_interpreter":"/usr/bin/python"